# What are eigenfrequencies of guided electromagnetic waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, frequency, software, waveguide

I am using a commercial software (COMSOL) to find modes in dielectric waveguides. Each mode is associated with an eigenfrequency. In this context, what is an eigenfrequency?

Answer (score 1):

*Eigenvalues* are the solutions to certain types of *partial differential equations*, like linear, second order PDEs with bound solutions.

The OP indicated (in the comments) the phenomenon under study is described by the Helmholz equation, which is in essence a wave equation.

Grand examples are the Wave Equation, the Diffusion Equation, the Fourier Heat Equation and the Schrodinger Equation.

Comment: Do you mean that eigenfrequencies are the eigenvalues of these partial differential equations?

Comment: Yes, precisely. Can you post the PDE that governs your phenomenon?

Comment: It's the Helmholtz equation in electromagnetics. I'll post the exact equation when I get back home. Thanks!

Comment: Okay. Very well.

Comment: Helmholtz eq.: $\nabla^2A=-k^2 A$. With suitable boundaries this will give eigenfunctions.